# Imbalanced dataset with 3 classes xgboost scale_pos_weight parameter

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost

The xgboost classifier states the use of parameter `scale_pos_weight` for 2-class problems.

I have a highly imbalanced dataset with 3 classes. Classes '1' and '-1' are very rare (~1% of dataset) and class '0' is very common.

How do I set this `scale_pos_weight` parameter in the xgboost classifier correctly for my classification problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the best way for handling the imbalanced dataset in your case is setting `scale_pos_weight` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

For my multiclass classification problem with similar unbalanced data I used the output from sklearn `compute_class_weight` function:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html

```
sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight, classes, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `scale_pos_weight` works for two classes (binary classification).

The parameter `weight` goes into the `xgb.DMatrix` function can be used for three or more classes. The weights can be computed like this:

```
weights = total_samples / (n_classes * class_samples * 1.0)
```